# How to edit constraint in code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, constraints

I have a web page that start with a width constrain of 100.

When the user click a button i want to change the constrain to : 200.

I tried this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constrain = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                 constraintWithItem:self.webPage
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:self.webPage
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 multiplier:1
                                 constant:100];




[self.webPage addConstraint:constrain];
```

But this throws out this exception :
"Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Get a reference to the original constraint and change the `constant` part to 200
2. Get a reference to the original constraint and remove it from the view, and add the new constraint

I would go for the first option. To get a reference add a `@property` for the constraint to your viewController and assign it when you create it.

If you are creating the constraint in a xib or storyboard connect the constraint with a IBOutlet connection to your code, similar to what you do when you connect a UILabel.

You can then easily adjust the constant part of the constraint.

---

Also you constraint should probably be more along these lines:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                 constraintWithItem:self.webPage
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                 toItem:nil
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                 multiplier:1
                                 constant:100];
```

Comment: Great, can you show how to access the original constraint (which was done in IB)?

Comment: Connect the constraint to an IBOutlet. Similar like you do it when you  connect a UILabel or something.

Comment: Any idea on how i can make the constrain change with animation?

Comment: @oopsi, if you want to animate it, change the value of the constant inside the animations block of animateWithDuration:animations:, and call [superview layoutIfNeeded] where "superview" is whatever view the constraint was added to.

Comment: Great! I didn't know we could do that.

Answer (score 9):

if you want to set the width don't have a toItem: set.

```
_myConstrain = [NSLayoutConstraint
                             constraintWithItem:self.webPage
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                             toItem:nil
                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                             multiplier:1
                             constant:100];

// add to superview! not to self.webPage 
[self.view addConstraint:_myConstrain];
```

When you want to change it later:

```
_myConstrain.constant = 200.0f; 
[self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // you may be able to call this on self.webPage
```

Comment: Brilliant approach.