# Changing an Autolayout-constrained UIView's frame at runtime in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

For example, I use this code to change the frame position of a `UIView` called `Propo`:

```
        self.Propo.frame.origin.x -= self.view.frame.width
```

(`Propo` has constraints in Storyboard)

But When the app view disappears and reappears, the `UIView` resets itself to its original position. How can I do to resolve it? I want the `UIView` to keep its position when I change it programmatically.

I've tried `updateViewConstraints()` by anything else append...

Comment: Never change the frame if the view has constraints!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constraints and manual frame manipulation are directly in conflict. You have to choose one or the other. You should instead "promote" the constraint you wish to change by Ctrl-dragging it to your view controller as an @IBOutlet in Storyboard. Then, you can manipulate its constant:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myPropoLeftEdgeConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBAction doChangePropo(sender: AnyObject) {
        myPropoLeftEdgeConstraint.constant -= view.frame.width
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

This is already covered in Objective C in many places, so just do a search on programmatically changing an NSLayoutConstraint in code if you can read those examples.

[How to edit constraint in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897353/how-to-edit-constraint-in-code)

(Edit to make more applicable: generally constraints should be animated for a clean user experience. Otherwise the eye is confused.)

You can easily animate the constraint adjustment by wrapping `view.layoutIfneeded` in a `UIView.animateWithDuration(duration) { ... }` block.

Comment: Thank You BaseZen !